# R: Merging two datasets with two columns as conditions

Tags: merge

I would like to merge two datasets "follower_information" and "post_information".
The first criterion for the merge is that the columns "follower_information$influencer" and "post_information$username" clearly match. In addition, the posts may only be +/- three days apart, which can be conditioned by the columns "post_information$time_add" and "follower_information$date".

My code so far with the help of ChatGPT looks like this, but I'm getting error messages here. In addition, is there a way to increase the memory limit in R as the "memory.limit()" function does not work anymore?

#Set the tolerance for date matching (in days)
tolerance <- 3

#Convert date columns to Date format
follower_information$date_formatchange <- as.Date(follower_information$date)
post_information_clean$time_add_formatchange <- as.Date(post_information_clean$time_add)

#perform the merge based on influencer and date within the tolerance
merged_data <- follower_information %>%
left_join(post_information_clean, by = c("influencer" = "username", relationship = "many-to-many")) %>%
filter(abs(date_formatchange - time_add_formatchange) <= tolerance)

All rows that do not match these criterions should be excluded from the new formed dataset "merged_data". All columns should be kept, also the matching criterion columns.

I would be grateful for any input!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.